# Run middleware before executing apollo client mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo-client, dry

I have a custom hook that manages crud actions for any given entity.

That hook is also managing server error state based on error response of create, update and delete mutations.

Before each mutation is run , I would like to clear my serverErrors state.

What I am currently doing is wrapping each mutation in order to first reset serverErrors state and then passing along mutation args like so:

```
  const [_deleteGroups, { loading: deleteLoading }] = useMutation(DELETE_GROUPS_MUTATION, {
    onError: (error) => {
      setServerErrors((serverErrors) => ({ ...serverErrors, ...extractServerError(error) }));
    },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      onDeleteComplete && onDeleteComplete(data);
    },
    update: (cache, { data }) => {
      const { updateGroup } = data;
      cache.updateQuery({ query: GET_GROUP_BY_ID, variables: { groupId: updateGroup.id } }, () => updateGroup);
    },
  });

  const deleteGroups = useCallback(
    (args) => {
      setServerErrors((serverErrors) => ({ ...serverErrors, network: undefined }));
      _deleteGroups(args);
    },
    [_deleteGroups]
  );
```

Whilst this works, it's definitely not in line with DRY principles, because I have to recreate every mutation.

Is there no way to execute some arbitrary code before each mutation is run? Something like skip from useQuery??

Comment: Use a custom [link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/)